# Centring Path shape inside Frame SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, path, uibezierpath

I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and I have been playing around with `Path` and `UIBezierPath` anyway I have been attempting to render out some Kanji (Chinese/Japanese Characters) using some UIBezierPath data from a project I found online, however, I can't seem to centre the Path inside a frame and wondering what might be going wrong?

[Image of Kanji bursting out of frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjrvg.png)

Is there a way to easily centre the paths inside the frame?

The code that produces the output of the attached image is...

```swift
struct KanjiDrawView: View {
    let paths: [UIBezierPath]
    
    init(paths: [UIBezierPath]) {
        self.paths = paths
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            ForEach(paths, id: \.self) { path in
                Path(path.cgPath)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 4)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It can be done easily together with Geometry reader , If its possible to add ur path , then I can add some code example too

Comment: Hi @jonno, I think the problem is that the Path is to big. What happens when you make the frame of the zstack 400 x 400? I haven't worked with paths yet but maybe you can try the modifier .resizable() on the path and then set a frame of 200x200.

Comment: @Yodagama Hmm I did try that and it didn't seem to work, perhaps I might be doing it incorrectly. Also the UIBezierPaths have been pre-calculated from its original source https://kanjivg.tagaini.net basically someone pre-processed all these SVGs into UIBezierPaths

Comment: @Lukas thank you for your reply, unfortunately `Path` doesn't seem to have a resizable modifier  it does let me set the frame of it, which seems to shrink it down nicely but doesn't centre it

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/scaling-an-uibezierpath-for-a-custom-swiftui-shape-c6d1d6c30a88

Comment: @Jonno yeah just putting GeometryReader does not work . you have to relatively draw your path . if you can post one of ur path then i cn add how to do that

Comment: @Yodagama my apologies one of the paths is

```swift <UIBezierPath: 0x6000035d4f60; <MoveTo {54.5, 20}>,
 <CurveTo {54.279998779296875, 26.270000457763672} {54.869998931884766, 22.119998931884766} {54.729999542236328, 24.030000686645508}>,
 <CurveTo {16.5, 87.25} {51.680000305175781, 39.479999542236328} {38.25, 72.25}>```